# Doing SELECT from a VIEW is very slow

Tags: postgresql

I have a table say `tbl_test`. In this table I have `2.4 million` records. I run the following three queries which are very very slow and frustrating.

```
select count(*) from tbl_test;
-- 2.4 mil records in ~9 seconds

select count(*) from tbl_test where status = 'active';
-- 2.4 mil records in ~9 seconds

select count(*) from tbl_test where status = 'inactive';
-- 0 records in ~0 seconds
```

I have created a view say `view_tbl_test` using the following query:

```
create view view_tbl_test as 
  select * from 
   (select count(*) count_active from tbl_test where status = 'active' ) x,
   (select count(*) count_inactive from tbl_test where status = 'inactive' ) y,
   (select count(*) count_total from tbl_test) z
```

Now, I am picking only the single row from the view and its taking the same amount of time like previous.

```
select * from view_tbl_test limit 1;
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there any way which can make the view to return data in `~0` seconds?

Comment: Why do you think that selecting from a simple view (not materialized view) would be faster?

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko will it return results in no times if I use Materialized view?

Answer (score 0):

Your statement runs three selects on the table. This can be done with a single statement:

```
create view view_tbl_test 
as 
select count(case when status = 'active' then 1 end) as count_active
       count(case when status = 'inactive' then 1 end) as count_inactive, 
       count(*) as count_total
from tbl_test;
```

This should run in approx. 9seconds as it essentially does the same as your first statement.

The last statement is probably that fast because you have an index on `status` but as you did not provide the execution plans, this is nearly impossible to tell.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It says `ERROR: syntax error at or near "when"` when I ran on my pc. I have index on `status` but that's not the point. I am wandering why the actual count queries and the select from view are equal! From my understanding, selecting from a view should be faster.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Why do you think selecting from the view should be faster? It's not a "single" query - it's three queries and each one is retrieving the rows from the table again. So it retrieving from the view should take actually 18 seconds: 9 seconds for the `count_active` query and 9 seconds for the `count_total` query. If it doesn't it just shows that Postgres can optimize that. But again as you didn't supply and execution plan at all this is impossible to tell